# Gnome-terminal padding only when fullscreen?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, fullscreen

I'd like to add padding to the left and right of my terminal when in full screen so that the terminal itself doesn't actually take up the whole screen. I can get the exact effect I want by editing `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and adding :

```
vte-terminal {
    padding: 20px 250px 20px 250px;
}
```

But then when I don't run the terminal in full screen, it is basically all padding and becomes unusable. What I'd like is 0 padding unless its full screen, then apply that css. Is this possible? is there another way to do it? A different terminal that has this function? I thought since css, maybe you could use media rules, but those don't seem to be implemented from what I've looked into.

Comment: Ubuntu release/version?

Comment: That is not possible. Find a compromise and use small padding that also works when not full screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It surprises me this isn't a more common request. Especially with the ultrawide monitors that exist today. Do people just not use fullscreen? I like the immersion, but maybe I'm strange.

I am using Cinnamon atm. I do use i3wm as well, but lately have been using mainly Cinnamon. Anyway, here is my hacky work around.

I installed the terminal "Guake", which has a terminal always open in the background, that you can bring to the foreground with a shortcut key.

I created the `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and added:

```
vte-terminal {
  padding: 20px 250px 20px 250px;
}
```

But then changed its name to `gtk.css.something`.

Then wrote a small script that `cd` to that containing folder, renames the file to the proper name, launches `gnome-terminal` in full screen and then changes the name back to including an extension that disables it.

So, I start `guake`, execute my script and I have a full screen terminal.

If I need a quick terminal just for a calculator or to check something, I use Guake. While I'm coding or doing something more involved, I use the full screen terminal.

I'll admit it's not a great solution, and I'm not 100% happy with it. Its clunky and not perfect, but it has been working for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want padding, then I would suggest using a tiling window manager like Awesome WM as this is not possible in Gnome.

See [r/UnixPorn](https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/) for great examples of what they can do, and DistroTube made [a great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKtit_B7Keo&t=1429s) on how to set it up as well.